Show that L={a^nb^m:n>m} is a deterministic context-free language
Above language L is a context-free language, but I found that this language can only represented by the NPDA. Because the conditions of DPDA(Deterministic PDA) says:
If $\delta(q, \lambda, b)$ is not empty, then $\delta(q, c, b)$ must be empty for every $c\in\Sigma$.
NPDA I found :
$M=(Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, z, F)$
Where $Q=\{q_0, q_1, q_2\}, \Sigma=\{a, b\}, \Gamma=\{A,z\}, F=\{q_2\}$
Transition function $\delta$:
$\delta(q_0, a, z) = \{(q_0, Az)\},  \delta(q_0, a, A) = \{(q_0, AA)\}, \delta(q_0, \lambda, A) = \{(q_1, A)\}$
$\delta(q_1, b, A) = \{(q_1, \lambda)\}, \delta(q_1, \lambda, A) = \{(q_2, A)\}$

With three states, no $\varepsilon$-transition:

